# Android API 15: AsyncTask not running (Android Studio 1.3.2)

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 15
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.justmakan.androidhive"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'}
    }
}
```

This is my android build.gradle.

```
class get_Username extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
                params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
                json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_username, "POST", params);
                Log.e("User Response: ", "> " + json);
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt("success");
                    if (success == 1) {
                        JSONArray usernames = json.getJSONArray("users");

                        for(int g = 0; g < usernames.length(); g++)
                        {
                            JSONObject o = usernames.getJSONObject(g);
                            username = o.getString("username");
                        }

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void file_url)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(file_url);}
}
```

class get_Username is my asynctask that is not running in my owner main activity

```
public class Owner extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.owner_activity);

    spinnerLocation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLocation);
    spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFood);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    inputDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);

   // spinnerLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // getting product details from intent

    Intent tempI = getIntent();
    user_id = tempI.getStringExtra("user_id");

    new get_Username().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    inputUsername.setText(username);
    inputUsername.setEnabled(false);
```

Owner Activity that suppose to be show the username on TextView inputUsername column

```
<?php

$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['user_id'])) 
{

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

require_once 'db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());

    $response["users"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $users = array();
        $users["username"] = $row["username"]
        array_push($response["users"], $users);
    }

    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing json result
    echo json_encode($response);}   

 else {
 $response["success"] = 0;
 $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

 echo json_encode($response);}

?>
```

get_username_by_userid.php in server folder through android by using JsonParser.

Currently, I'm developing an android app that allow user to login and sendthe user_id in mySQL to the owner activity, the TextView should show the user to see his or her username on the column from get_user. Thank for advance.

Comment: where is your variable `username` declared?

Comment: @NicholasAllio it is under class Owner, I removed it due to there has too many varables declared

Comment: As [DGN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32882490/2064585) proposed, you should modify the custom AsyncTask and return your value in `onPostExecute` method; that one is the only method able to communicate with the main thread where your `Owner` Activity is running.

Answer (score 1):

FYI,This has nothing to do with build.gradle and Android Studio version.

Please check your doInBackground() method. You are returning 'null' here. You are supposed to return the required String here. Catch the result in postExecute()

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String value)
{
   //Update your UI here using 'value'
  //  super.onPostExecute(file_url);}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does I need to edit on Asynctask <Void, Void, String> instead to return values? It is return null but variable 'username' is declare under all class(global) so if the method has update the value of username and used in owner class

Comment: In that case, you are setting the ' inputUsername.setText(username); ' before getting the AsyncTask result. just place it in onPostExecute() method in AsyncTask so that you can check the value.

Comment: I modified it under onPostExecute() like:

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    inputUsername.setText(username);
                    inputUsername.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });

and return username after retrieve at the end of doingInBackground().

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

this is the error I get now

Comment: Log show that it was still null. Is there any logic errors inside my doinbackground()? and Error parsing data..

Comment: Can you log the 'echo' ed value  you get as output from php code.  Just want to see the json code.

Answer (score 0):

use @Override top of your doingInbackgroud and use

```
new get_Username().executeOnExecutor();
```

instead of

```
new get_Username().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: Pirisok , It can't be implement due to error as below:

error: method executeOnExecutor in class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> cannot be applied to given types;
required: Executor,Void[]
found: no arguements
reason: actual and formal arguements lists differ in length